# Is there a way to lower the DPI scale to less than 100 in Windows 11 to fit more data on the screen?

Tags: windows, windows-11, dpi

I have a 42-inch TV but when I connect it to the computer, the amount of data that fits on the screen is exactly the same when I turn the computer on to a 21-inch monitor.

On old Windows and Android, you can edit the DPI scale to whatever you want, doing this I can put a lot more things on the same screen, with smaller scales (as if I had zoomed out a little, let's say).

Answer (score 3):

To scale below 100% was available as a feature in Windows 7 & 8,
but has been dropped in Windows 10. The interface provided by Windows
10 & 11 does not expose any such function.

The simplest way to zoom-out is to increase the screen resolution,
if it is available as an option by the display driver and the
display adapter, as long as you don't run into any limits.

If you have a separate graphic card that is not part of your CPU,
the software that comes with that card might provide this option.

For example, with a Nvidia GPU, the Nvidia Control Panel in the
"Manage 3D settings", scroll to "DSR - Factors", where DSR stands for
Dynamic Super Resolution. Here you can select factors of multiplication
to your current screen display resolution.
This can help, for example, if your current screen is limited to 1080p
but your monitor is 4K-capable.

Answer (score 1):

The next solution works in all GPUs and in both Windows 10 and Windows 11, even if you have low resolution:

1. Install and create a Virtual Monitor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybHKFZjSkVY
2. Then go to Settings > System > Display
3. Next, click where it says "Extend these displays" and select "Duplicate these displays"
4. Select "Keep these changes"
5. Finally, go to "Display resolution" and select the maximum resolution possible.

If icons and text look too small you can increase the scaling.

What this does is to trick the system to think that you have a very large resolution so you can make objects in the screen smaller.

This is done this way when you have only one monitor, when you have more than one, the thing is a bit more complex.

I hope this solution was useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me with multiple monitors, the maximum resolution possible simply matched the resolution of the existing screens.